# Textbook Page Design and Layout

Tags: spacing, equations, minipage

I have no formal background in graphic design. I am putting together a short handout for students. At the moment, there are about 10 pages of a portrait oriented pdf handout and eventually I would like to have a landscape oriented Beamer presentation as well.

If anyone has a good resource of textbook industry best practices for laying out this type of content, please feel free to pass it along.

I'm pasting the first page to provide an example of the content and the MWE for what has been tried so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[letterpaper, portrait, margin=.75in,headheight=35pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{rodbox}
    {
    \begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!10, arrondi=0.1, logo=\hspace{.1pt}, ombre=true, barre=none]{}\centering}
    {\end{bclogo}\endcenter}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{\Large{The Simple Rule of Three}}
\end{center}

Many times in chemistry we need to figure out how much of one thing we need to make a different thing. There is a math technique we use called \textit{The Simple Rule of Three} to help you calculate this. We call the resulting setup a \textit{proportion} and use \textit{cross-multiplication} to find the answer.

Here is a very simple example. Let's begin by saying you have four apple trees. You collect all the apples and count them. You have 300 apples. So far, so good, right?

Now comes the fun part. You want to start an applesauce factory, but you need at least 1000 apples to make that applesauce. How many trees do you need so that you can collect 1000 apples? Well you can use \textit{The Simple rule of Three} to find the answer.

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
First you set up the information you know, "Four trees gives 300 apple," which can be written like this ...
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin {rodbox}
4 trees = 300 apples
\vspace{5pt}
\end{rodbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
Then you add the information you are trying to calculate exactly underneath.
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{rodbox}
$\frac{\colorbox{blue!10}{4 trees}}{\colorbox{blue!10}{How many trees?}} = \frac{\colorbox{blue!10}{300 apples}}{\colorbox{blue!10}{1000 apples}}$
\vspace{5pt}
\end{rodbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
Now comes the \textit{cross-multiplication} part. Let's replace the "How many trees?" with an X. 
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{rodbox}
\psset{boxsize=.2,linewidth=.5pt,linecolor=black!30,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!15}% Boxes
\[
  \frac{\Rnode{lt}{\psframebox[fillcolor=red!30,linecolor=red]{\strut{4 \textnormal{ trees}}}}}{\Rnode{lb}{\psframebox[fillcolor=green!30,linecolor=green]{\strut{\textnormal{X}}}}} \rnode{eq}{\phantom{=}} \frac{\Rnode{rt}{\psframebox[fillcolor=green!30,linecolor=green]{\strut{300\textnormal{ apples}}}}}{\Rnode{rb}{\psframebox[fillcolor=red!30,linecolor=red]{1000\textnormal{ apples}}}}
\]
\psset{angleA=0,angleB=180,fillstyle=none}
\nccurve{<->}{lt}{rb}\nccurve{<->}{lb}{rt}\rput(eq){=}
\vspace{5pt}
\end{rodbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
Then we match up the values.
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{rodbox}
4 trees * 1000 apples = 300 apples * X trees
\vspace{5pt}
\end{rodbox}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
or...
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{rodbox}
$\textnormal{X trees} = \frac{\colorbox{red!30}{\strut{4 \textnormal{ trees}}} * \colorbox{red!30}{\strut{1000\textnormal{ apples}}}}{\colorbox{green!30}{\strut{300\textnormal{ apples}}}} = \frac{\colorbox{blue!10}{4000}}{\colorbox{blue!10}{300}} = \colorbox{blue!10}{13.33 \textnormal{ trees}}$
\vspace{5pt}
\end{rodbox}
\end{minipage}


So we know that we will need to have a total of 14 trees (sig figs!) to get enough apples to make applesauce. 

See, how simple was that? Are you ready to try this with some real chemistry?


\end{document}
```

Comment: IMHO The font does not look very professional, I'd rather use a serif font for printed material. And mixing indented first lines of paragraphs with space between the paragraphs looks unruly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just have to point out that in this problem the normal chemistry significant figures principles don't apply at all because the number of apples and the number of trees are both known exactly due to the fact that they were counted, not measured with a device. The uncertainty instead comes from an unknown experimental value for the standard deviation of the number of apples a given apple tree will create.

I would suggest sticking to a simple chemistry problem as the example, although I'm really not aware of what level what you are writing is aimed at. Also I am interested to know why the technique is called "the rule of three".

Comment: This is the first of several pages. Each subsequent page is the application of the rule to chemistry problems. Wolfram explains it better than I  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RuleofThree.html

Comment: Oh okay "rule of three" because three of the numbers are known. It might be nice to include an explanation of the name in the page